# wordpress folder / slug redirect

Tags: .htaccess

how do I redirect a category or page /my-page/ to a new page /my-new-page/ using htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Add this above the existing rules (but after RewriteEngine On):

`RewriteRule ^/?my\-page /my-new-page [R=301,L]`

Comment: This was tested and does work on both Apache 1.x and 2.x servers.

Answer (score 0):

This works: Redirect 301 /my-page/ http://mydomain.com/my-new-page/